# getting error in below multi threaded program

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I java the below java code which s showing compilation errors , please advise how can i overcome from this

```
    public class Chaining {

    import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

    public class Chaining {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
              CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10))// ** getting compilation error ***
                               .thenApply(Math::sqrt)
                               .thenAccept(System.out::println)
                               .join();
          }

}
}
```

Comment: use Alt+Enter?.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: you have the class declaration twice

Answer (score 1):

It should be this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Chaining {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10))// ** getting compilation error ***
                .thenApply(Math::sqrt)
                .thenAccept(System.out::println)
                .join();
    }

}
```

Please learn to utilise your IDE's features.

Comment: also please advise  want to see the intermediate value in between, like in streams we have peek can i also see in between

Comment: @NeeraSaxena I don't know about that, and that begs another question. If this solves your current problem then accept and close it.